# Rotate vector using Java 3D

Tags: rotation, java-3d

I'm attempting to use Java3D to rotate a vector.  My goal is create a transform that will make the vector parallel with the y-axis.  To do this, I calculated the angle between the original vector and an identical vector except that it has a z value of 0 (original x, original y, 0 for z-value).  I then did the same thing for the y-axis (original x, 0 for y-value, original z).  I then used each angle to create two Transform3D objects, multiply them together and apply to the vector.  My code is as follows:

```
Transform3D yRotation = new Transform3D();
Transform3D zRotation = new Transform3D();

//create new normal vector
Vector3f normPoint = new Vector3f (normal.getX(), normal.getY(), normal.getZ());

//****Z rotation methods*****
Vector3f newNormPointZ = new Vector3f(normal.getX(), normal.getY(),0.0F);
float zAngle = normPoint.angle(newNormPointZ);
zRotation.rotZ(zAngle);

//****Y rotation methods*****
Vector3f newNormPointY = new Vector3f(normal.getX(),0.0F, normal.getZ());
float yAngle = normPoint.angle(newNormPointY);
yRotation.rotY(yAngle);

//combine the two rotations
yRotation.mul(zRotation);

System.out.println("before trans normal = " +normPoint.x + ", "+normPoint.y+", "+normPoint.z);
//PRINT STATEMENT RETURNS: before trans normal = 0.069842085, 0.99316376, 0.09353002

//perform transform 
yRotation.transform(normPoint);

System.out.println("normal trans = " +normPoint.x + ", "+normPoint.y+", "+normPoint.z);
//PRINT STATEMENT RETURNS: normal trans = 0.09016449, 0.99534255, 0.03411238
```

I was hoping the transform would produce x and z values of or very close to 0.  While the logic makes sense to me, I'm obviously missing something..

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to rotate a vector parallel to the y axis, why can't you just manually set it using the magnitude of the vector and setting your vector to <0, MAGNITUDE, 0>?

Also, you should know that rotating a vector to be directly pointing +Y or -Y can cause some rotation implementations to break, since they operate according to the "world up" vector, or, <0,1,0>.  You can solve this by building your own rotation system and using the "world out" vector <0,0,1> when rotating directly up.

If you have some other purpose for this, [fastgraph](http://www.fastgraph.com/makegames/3drotation/) helped me with building rotation matrices.

It's best to understand the math of what's going on so that you know what to do in the future.

Comment: Thanks.  My overall goal is to rotate an entire pointcloud so the floor has values very close to or equal to 0.  I'm trying to generate a Transform3D that will rotate the vector (normal to the floor) parallel to the y-axis and then use that same Transform3D to rotate every point in the pointcloud.  After the rotation I'm hoping all points belonging to the floor will have a value very close to zero.  Does that sound like a decent approach?

Comment: The location of each point will depend on the axis of rotation. If I recall correctly, the RotX/Y/Z functions rotate using each object's modelview matrix, so rotating a point that has been moved to (a,b,c), will result in the point still being located in (a,b,c), but with a different normal direction.

[AxisAngle4f](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/desktop/java3d/forDevelopers/J3D_1_3_API/j3dapi/javax/vecmath/AxisAngle4f.html) seems to be what you want.